# Deny NTFS permission

Tags: powershell, ntfs

How can I deny NTFS permission (permission to Write for some user)? 
I have to prove it with Get-NTFSAccess, so I can't use Remove-NTFSAccess.

I'm using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Account "User X" -Path PathToFile -AccessRights write -AccessType Deny
```

Comment: I am not shure that I fully understand your question but NTFSAccess is an addition, so you can't use it before instalation. And it let you chanege the access rights for particular users or group of users.  (It is Windows PowerShell command, you means that?)

Comment: Yes, I install it first. I used those comends: 
1) Find-Module NTFS* 
2) Install-Module NTFSSecurity
3) Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
4) Import-Module NTFSSecurity
And to test it:
5) Get-NTFSAccess .